# Setting custom navbar background color with bg- class in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

According to the Bootstrap 4 [migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/), "Navbars now require a background declaration of some kind. Choose from our background utilities (`.bg-*`) or set your own with the light/inverse classes above for mad customization."

I tried adding the class `bg-navbar` (made up) and setting the background for that class, but the colors didn't apply. Then I changed it to `bg-custom` and the colors applied.

Why does `bg-custom` work while `bg-navbar` doesn't? Is `bg-custom` is an official class? If so, I can't find it in the official docs. I was thinking it just had to start with `bg-` to work, and what comes after (unless you're using one of the official classes, of course) doesn't matter.

This doesn't work:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-navbar">

.bg-navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8259cb 0, #673ab7 100%);
}
```

But this does (I only changed `bg-navbar` to `bg-custom`):

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-custom">

    .bg-custom {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8259cb 0, #673ab7 100%);
    }
```

**Update: The problem was an issue with compiling. I had `bg-custom` set before, but the SCSS wasn't compiled correctly after changing it to `bg-navbar`.**

Comment: What is `bg-navbar`? a custom class? These are the Bootstrap 4 available `bg-classes`: [Bootstrap 4 Background Color](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color)

Comment: Yes, it's a custom class. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update 1:

With your `bg-navbar`, the navbar still works fine:

[image]

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/285463/

---

#### Original

I wish you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to show us what you have done and what the problem is.

Here I made up the `bg-navbar` and set its background to red and it worked:

```
.bg-navbar {
    background: red;
}
```

[image]

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/285429/

There is no `bg-custom` class!

And there is no magic about `bg-` prefix. Adding `bg-*` worked because those are predefined background classes in `bootstrap4`:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/#background-color

[image]

#### Conclusion

See how important it is to show us what you have done and your code?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think the code used was relevant since the only difference was the name of the class as mentioned in the question. However, I've added the bits of code that I changed for clarification.